# IF-statement not working in this method using nokogiri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

This is my simple code. I've problems with this *IF statement* that is looking for a element for each item in the array.

Now my problem is that the code gets stuck in the first part of the IF-statements. The 2 items that I've inside **train_tables** have just one **TrainPathNotAvailable**. I should expect that if one the items doesnt have **TrainPathNotAvailable** it should print out **'second IN'** BUT it doesnt
right?

thanks for yr time!
the url for the code: [here](https://github.com/yonipacheko/train_check/blob/master/app/models/timetable.rb)

```
 def self.opening_file
    @train_at_path_locations
    doc = Nokogiri::XML(File.open("test_with_path.xml"))
    @train_tables = doc.css("TrainTimeTable")

    puts @train_tables.count # I have just 2 items to make this test easy

    @train_tables.each do |i|

      @train_id = i.css('TrainIdent PathIdent')
      @train_locations = i.css('TrainAtPathLocation')

      if i.css('TrainPathNotAvailable')  #here is the problem
        puts 'first IN'
        # @first_station_not_available = i.css('FromLocationIdent LocationSubsidiaryCode')
        # puts @train_location_last = i.css('ToLocationIdent LocationSubsidiaryCode').text
        break
      else
        puts 'second IN'
        # @train_location_first = i.css('TrainAtPathLocation LocationIdent LocationSubsidiaryCode').first
        #
        # puts @train_location_last = i.css('TrainAtPathLocation LocationIdent LocationSubsidiaryCode').last
      end

    end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try at_css instead of css.

css will return an empty array, [], when it doesn't find anything and this is a truthy value causing your if statement to fire.

at_css will return nil if it finds nothing.

if you need an array returned, try css().any?

Comment: Thanks man!! did know about this... when did u get this info? GRacias!

Comment: By looking at the nokogiri docs 

http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-at_css
http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-css

and then using irb to test out what I thought was happening with the different methods.